# Installing GeoJSON preview plugin on CKAN

Tags: geospatial, json, ckan

I've managed to stand up a CKAN instance, and would now like to preview GeoJSON data in CKAN. According to the [ckanext-spatial documentation](http://ckanext-spatial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), I don't need to install the full ckanext-spatial package, I only need to add `resource_proxy geojson_preview` to my `ckan.plugins`variable in my config file.

I'm able to successfully add `resource_proxy`, but when I add `geojson_preview` and restart my server, I get a 500 error. The server logs report a PluginNotFoundException. I assume this is referring to the ckanext-spatial plugin, which I'd prefer not to install (includes PostGIS, etc) is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you still need to do the steps on the ["Install the extension"](http://ckanext-spatial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#install-the-extension) section to enable the plugin.

As an aside, we will move the geospatial previews to a separate CKAN extension to avoid this issue of having to install the `ckanext-spatial` requirements. I'll add a note here when it's done, or keep an eye on the [ckan-dev](https://lists.okfn.org/mailman/listinfo/ckan-dev) mailing list.

Comment: Great-- thanks! I'll be on the lookout for that update.

Comment: The separate CKAN extension for geospatial previews is [ckanext-geoview](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-geoview).